# MAC Address vendor lookup and model detection

Tags: python, mac-address

I apologize if there is already a Thread about this.

I'm currently thinking of a Python script that pings a specific host, captures its MAC address and compares it with a .txt-File which contains the common 24-bits of a Mac address that corresponds to the specific manufacturer.

You can get the .txt File [here](https://gist.github.com/aallan/b4bb86db86079509e6159810ae9bd3e4).

If you look at that file you may notice, that one manufacturer (e.g. XEROX CORPORATION, line 4-9) can posses more than one "MAC Address segment". My question now is: Is there a way to tell what kind of hardware is usually using this MAC (for example "000003", XEROX CORPORATION)? Is it a printer, computer or maybe even a network device like a switch?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only XEROX can tell you whether they use different MAC ranges for different devices. This is their internal business, they are in no way required to disclose how they assign numbers to devices. The only info that is publicly available is which ranges are registered for their use.